# disable cancel button GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController when Play Now Pressed

Tags: game-center

'
I have a problem with GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController. When I display GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController and then I press "Play Now" button to find automatch. While Its processing I press the cancel Button after this application crashes.. It never comes in didFindMatch function.. It crashes before that.

Can we disable the cancel button while once "Play Now" Pressed?

Following is my code for GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate

`
 #pragma GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate functions

```
// The user has cancelled
- (void)turnBasedMatchmakerViewControllerWasCancelled:(GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController *)viewController {
[presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(gameCenterViewControllrRemoved)]) {
    [self.delegate gameCenterViewControllrRemoved];
}
self.delegate = nil;
presentingViewController = nil;
}

// Matchmaking has failed with an error
- (void)turnBasedMatchmakerViewController:(GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController *)viewController didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
[presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(gameCenterViewControllrRemoved)]) {
    [self.delegate gameCenterViewControllrRemoved];
}
self.delegate = nil;
presentingViewController = nil;
}

// A turned-based match has been found, the game should start
- (void)turnBasedMatchmakerViewController:(GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController *)viewController didFindMatch:(GKTurnBasedMatch *)match
{
[presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[self setCurrentMatch:match];
GKTurnBasedParticipant *firstParticipant = [match.participants objectAtIndex:0];
if(self.delegate) {
    if (firstParticipant.lastTurnDate == NULL) {
        // It's a new game!
        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(startTurnBasedGame)]) {
            [self.delegate startTurnBasedGame];
        }
        //[self.delegate startTurnBasedGame];
    } else {
        if ([match.currentParticipant.playerID isEqualToString:[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].playerID]) {
            // It's your turn!
            if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(takeTurn)]) {
                [self.delegate takeTurn];
            }
        } else {
            // It's not your turn, just display the game state.
            if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(displayLayout)]) {
                [self.delegate displayLayout];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}
`

thanks

chishti

Comment: I have just tested this and in my case the when I press "play now" button the cancel button deactivates automatically. I have tested it on iOS 6.1. Please post your implementation of `GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate`, maybe there is something wrong there.

Comment: I am working in iOS 6.0. it could be problem?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code there.